# Xamarin UWP Azure App Service code

Tags: azure, xamarin, uwp

I have an Azure App service which I am connecting to from a Xamarin Forms App. I'm using the Todo list template code and I have the SQL Lite nuget package added to each project.

With the UWP project, it crashes on initialising the app, with the InnerException:

```
"You need to call SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider().  If you are using a bundle package, this is done by calling SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init()."
```

However, I'm unsure where to call this. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I have created xamarin forms app with azure mobile service. But in the uwp project I can not find the `SQLitePCL`. My project works fine.